# Is Form Field conversion possible in yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

Would it be possible to give checkM the following type instead:

```
checkM :: RenderMessage master msg => 
          (a -> GHandler sub master (Either msg b)) -> 
          Field sub master a -> Field sub master b
```

The reason is the following:

I have a form that asks for a user name. Using checkM, I immediately look up in the database whether the entered user exists:

```
userField = checkM userexists textField
userexists input = do
  mbuser <- runDB $ getBy $ UniqueName input
  return $ case mbuser of
    Nothing  -> Left ("This user does not exist!" :: Text)
    (Just (Entity uid _)) -> Right input 
    -- I would like to write "return Right uid" above!
```

However, I can only return input::Text, so right after the form has accepted the user input, I need to do another database lookup for the same name to get the database key for that user, which is what I really wanted.

(This example is largely simplified. Essentially, I want to get the database keys for a series of different user inputs (all in one form), which I can only ask as TextFields, or not?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the type signature looks that way is that there are two aspects to a `Field`: how you parse it, and how you render it. `checkM` only changes how you parse the field, but the rendering function (`fieldView`) remains unmodified. Therefore, the value needs to keep the same type.

The simplest way I can think of to get the behavior you want is to have a function which can get a value of the old type from a value of the new type. That way, given a new value, we can just apply that function to it and get the old value for rendering purposes. Here's what the code would look like:

```
checkM' :: RenderMessage master msg
        => (a -> GHandler sub master (Either msg b))
        -> (b -> a)
        -> Field sub master a
        -> Field sub master b
checkM' f inv field = field
    { fieldParse = \ts -> do
        e1 <- fieldParse field ts
        case e1 of
            Left msg -> return $ Left msg
            Right Nothing -> return $ Right Nothing
            Right (Just a) -> fmap (either (Left . SomeMessage) (Right . Just)) $ f a
    , fieldView = \i n a eres req -> fieldView field i n a (fmap inv eres) req
    }
```

So in your case, you could use it by changing the last line in `userexists` to:

```
(Just (Entity uid _)) -> Right (input, uid)
```

and then defining `userField` as

```
userField = checkM' userexists fst textField
```

I think a function like `checkM` makes sense to include in yesod-form, but hopefully with a better name ;).

Comment: Thanks! However, I wonder whether I am doing something fundamentally wrong, since I always seem to need this checkM'.

For example, I want to read in a list of int values through a form. The list can have arbitrary length (e.g. like oeis.org). I would again start with a textField and now use this checkM' to verify that it is indeed a well-formed list of integers. Does it really make sense to put the parsing into the field, or should this code better be included elsewhere?

Comment: (PS: There is not even a need for checkM', but rather check' here in the int list example, so really quickly generating any kind of field from just a function that can parse a value from a text (Text -> Either msg a) seems to be required, but since it isnt there, I just wonder what I am doing wrong.)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here, but even with a list of Ints you need to deal with the rendering second time around.